# Видимость переменной?

Tags: php

Есть файл на PHP в котором от API приходит ответ с токеном и записывается в переменную. Потом при нажатии на кнопочку `AJAX`-ом подгружается другой PHP файл где этот токен используется.

Как мне передать токен из отдного файла в другой?

Comment: Сохранить токен куда-нибудь помимо переменной, например в файл или в базу или в сессию

Comment: дайте, пожалуйста, пример

Comment: Работа с файлами, базами и сессиями есть в любом хорошем учебнике по php

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Для использования сессий - нужно использовать `session_start()`, а дальше уже `$_SESSION['key'] = 'value';`.

Comment: Cпасибо большое! теперь выдает ошибку Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at

Comment: В самое начало php кода необходимо вставить session_start();